# Using ionic 4,Trying to give an exit alert message to the user before the app gets closed using hardware back button press event

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

On my very initial stage.I am trying to give an ‘Exit the App - Yes/No? ‘  alert when the user presses the hardware back button either from the Login Page or from the home page (after login).  The problem I am facing is that the Exit alert message appears on every page when I press the back button and not simply on the Login or home page. Moreover  automatically navigating backwards regardless if I press ‘No’ option in the alert box. ]
Apologies if have done something wrong I this my first post here. 
The code I using attaching below-

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import{ Router } from '@angular/router';//
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-streams-list',
  templateUrl: './streams-list.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./streams-list.page.scss'],
})
export class StreamsListPage implements OnInit {

  subscripcion: Subscription;

  constructor(
    public router:Router,
    public alertController: AlertController) {}

  ngOnInit() {

    this.getBackButtonClick();

  }


  getBackButtonClick(){
    this.subscripcion = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{
        //navigator['app'].exitApp();
        this.ClosingApp();
    });
 }



  async ClosingApp()
 {
      let alert = await this.alertController.create({
      header: 'Confirm',
      message: 'Message to confirm!!!',
      buttons: [{
        text: "OK",
        handler: () => { this.exit() }
      }, {
        text: "Cancel",
        role: 'cancelar',
      }]
    })
     alert.present();
 }

 exit()
 {
  navigator["app"].exitApp();
 }


}
```

Comment: https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/5.4.0/cordova/events/events.backbutton.html try this if it helps

Comment: can you please provide any sample stacklblitz?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this approach based on routing. in `app.component.ts`

```
constructor(private router: Router){}
```

Inside your `getBackButtonClick()`

```
 getBackButtonClick(){
  this.subscripcion = this.platform.backButton.subscribe(()=>{
   if (this.route.url == '/login' || this.route.url == '/home'){ //please change if your path name is different for login and home
     this.ClosingApp();
    }
 });
}
```

Further you need to unsubscribe from this

```
  ngOnDestroy() {
   this.platform.backButton.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, after applying the If-else condition alert is not showing on when I press back button every time except "home page". But automatically navigating backwards regardless if I press ‘No’ option in the alert box . How can I prevent that?

Comment: did you write this in component class or app.component?  i have added the method, i hope it will solve your error.

Comment: yes I wrote this inside app.component , it is working now, But now I  am facing another issue, when I launch the app  and press back button the alert not comes up, but if I visit some other page from the " Home page " and navigate backward than the alert is showing. Page sequence is like  after login -                  HomePage-> page1->page2. I wrote the the if condition for homePage, after launching the app I if I press back button alert not showing. If I visit page 1 or page 2 and navigate back to home page again than the alert is showing.

Comment: what's your default launch page?

Comment: default page is login page. At the time of launch i check If the user is already logged  in by checking local storage, If  I found data in local storage I navigating to homePage.

Comment: so, this is happening in both the cases guest and logged in user ? i would recommend you to debug the code and check what's going wrong in the function. same code works fine for me in my app. must be a minor issue.

Comment: for both the cases this thing is happening.

Comment: please debug once and make sure you have removed previously implemented code in any component except app.component.

Comment: Yes , will do. can I ask for your mail-id

Comment: No, still working on it. I am new to ionic/angular.

Comment: If problem still persists you can put a demo app on stackblitz or something with code then i can check there.

Comment: The back button response is working now , but with an exception , I observing the devices which has back button inside the display (Soft back button) are not responding to the alert function unless you touch on the display once. In other devices working perfectly.

Comment: Now, that's something different. rest if my code works fine please upvote it :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to unsubscribe from that `this.platform.backButton` observable in `ngOnDestroy` lifecycle method like below :

```js
ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: @anirban As i understand you subscribe to `backButton` in your login page and you want it work for only in login page . But you don't clear your subscription. If you navigate to another page this subscription will be still  alive and if you push backbutton in another page it will still show you an alert as you define in your `ClosingApp` method. This piece of code clears your subscription to make it not working outside of login page.

Comment: can you please tell , where i have place and call this function?

Comment: @Ban you should place it where you subscribe `this.platform.backButton`

Comment: I placed just below exit(), is that ok ,  please check my code which have paste.