# ionic - subscribe back button to close internal div

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework

I have a "Search Filters" div which is displayed by `this.show_filters == true` condition.

Now I'm trying to use android back button to set this variable to false.

```
async toggleFiltersWindow(){
  console.log('#1 toggleFilters()');
  this.show_filters = !this.show_filters;

  // registrar evento do botao hardware BACK
  const event = fromEvent(document, 'backbutton');
  let self = this;
  if(this.show_filters == true){
    console.log('#2 BACK BT - subscribe');
    self.backbuttonSubscription = event.subscribe(async () => {
      console.log('#3 BACK BT - clicked');
      self.toggleFiltersWindow();
    });
  }else{
    self.backbuttonSubscription.unsubscribe();
    console.log('#4 BACK BT - unsubscribe');
  }
}
```

This code shows #1 and #2 console logs, but when I click back button nothing happens.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: So, you mean it's not detecting hardware back button?

Comment: exactly, @Mridul

Comment: In order to detect hardware button, platform.backbutton.subscribewithpriority(99999,()=>{do something...

Comment: @MostafaHarb could you post an example as answer, please?

Comment: @anderlaini, check this for backbutton https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59543013/using-ionic-4-trying-to-give-an-exit-alert-message-to-the-user-before-the-app-ge/59543736#59543736

Comment: You could try adding your own logic after subscribing. It's for reference.

Comment: I posted an example of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
backButtonEvent() { 
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(999999, () => { 
    // navigator['app'].exitApp();
    // or trigger any action you want to achieve
    }

}
```